# loop video clip in beamer

Tags: beamer, embedding, movie15

I am creating a presentation using beamer and would like to have my embedded video clip automatically play on a loop. I can get the video to appear and play in the pdf; however, it does not loop. I have tried different video formats (mp4,mpg,avi), all would play but none would loop. According to the beameruserguide.pdf, repeat should have the same effect as loop. Below is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%%%% PREAMBLE
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\title{Short Paper Title}
\author{Author's Name}
\institute[University of LaTeX]{
Department of Computer Science\\
Graphics Lab}
\begin{document}
%------------------- TITLE PAGE FRAME -------------------%
\begin{frame}[plain]
 \titlepage
\end{frame}
%------------------------ slide -------------------------%
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The frame title}
\begin{center}
   \movie[width=9.1cm,height=6.5cm,showcontrols=true,loop,poster]{}{video1.mp4}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Obviously, one would need to have the file "video1.mp4" on their local system to test this script.

edit: I have a default installation of TeXLive 2011 (downloaded from ctan.org) and use pdflatex to build my document.

Comment: Are you using Acrobat Reader to display the pdf document? In principle it should be able to include any animation that is supported by QuickTime. Otherwise you could try to re-encode the file into a different format. With other viewers such as xpdf one needs to use the externalviewer option to display the movie in a separate window.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [`movie15`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/movie15/) package and its `\includemovie` command? It is quite recent and promises `beamer` compatibility and looping movies. The movie shown in the documentation is indeed looping (Acrobat X, minimal Windows 7 installation).