# Gif image in LaTex Beamer

Tags: graphics, animations, animate, gif

I am trying to create an animation from given `*.png` files using the following code.

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{animate}
    \begin{document}
    \animategraphics[loop,autoplay]{6}{WT_t}{001}{143}

    \end{document}
```

The code runs perfectly and does not give any error but I do not see the image in generated pdf file. Can anyone please help me out?

2. I have a gif file too, is it possible to embed this image directly into my `beamer` presentation?

Comment: Which PDF viewer are your using? I don't think animations work in all viewers, the safest is Adobe Reader.

Comment: I am using Adobe reader (most updated version). I suspect that since size of image is large and it is not in center and within the page width. I do not know how  to deal with this.

Comment: Try: `\noindent\animategraphics[width=\linewidth,loop,autoplay]{6}{WT_t}{001}{143}`.

Comment: Hello AlexG, the code works fine but when I put this code inside " \begin{frame} and\end{frame} '. It does not run. Can you please have a look?

Comment: \begin{frame} {Results} \noindent\animategraphics[width=0.2\linewidth,loop,autoplay]‌​{6}{WT_t}{001}{143} \end{frame} I get an error saying "Package animate error:None of the files". I have already defined \usepackage{animate} and I am using \ProvidesClass{Bredelebeamer}. Please have a look.

Comment: You put "WT_t" as name for your images. The underscore produces the same error on my distribution. Removes the underscore, with a script or a tool like krename (linux) or lupas rename (windows), adapt the tex code and all will be fine. I don't know which versions of *animate* allows underscore in names, but I've used the same loop (with miketek), and now (with livetex), I must write names without underscore. With miketex, a year ago, it works with underscore in names, with livetex, now, underscores are forbidden.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\animategraphics` understands the same resizing, scaling and cropping options as package `graphicx`'s `\includegraphics`.

Thus, once you manage to rescale and include a single image file of the sequence  to your liking using `\includegraphics`, you can readily re-use those settings with `\animategraphics`, e.g.

```
\animategraphics[width=\linewidth,loop,autoplay]{6}‌​{WT_t}{001}{143}
```

**(2)** And no, there is no direct Gif support in PDF. The usual procedure to convert an existing animated Gif into a numbered PNG sequence is:

```
convert -coalesce something.gif something.png
```

Option `-coalesce` of ImageMagicks' `convert` command undoes a possible optimization of the Gif file to be converted.

Comment: Thank you very much. The code works using "\noindent\animategraphics[width=\linewidth,loop,autoplay]{6}‌​{WT_t}{001}{143}". But when I insert it inside the " \begin{frame} and\end{frame} '. It does not run. Can you please have a look?

Comment: @LatexUser : I ran a test with a set of PNGs of mine without any problem.

Comment: \begin{frame} {Results} \noindent\animategraphics[width=0.2\linewidth,loop,autoplay]‌​{6}{WT_t}{001}{143} \end{frame} I get an error saying "Package animate error:None of the files". I have already defined \usepackage{animate} and I am using \ProvidesClass{Bredelebeamer}. Please have a look.

Comment: @LatexUser TeX seems to be unable to find the image files `WT_t001.png` ... `WT_t143.png` . Verify writing and case (lowercase/uppercase) of the filename parts, including the extension. This may be one reason for the failure.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I checked everything but problem still persist. The very same code works outside the frame but not inside the frame.

Comment: Can you please run a test without this Bredelebeamer thing, just `\documentclass{beamer}` and `\usepackage{graphicx,animate}`. Noting else.

Comment: @LatexUser : I searched this forum, found [this comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308929/tcolorbox-header-error-with-bredelebeamer-class#comment750655_308929), and downloaded the latest version of the theme. I had no problem with compiling and viewing.

Comment: Thank you very much. My code works perfectly. I made a silly error in defining image location.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is old, I think it's still worth answering concerning the GIF part.

I've discovered the multimedia package (which comes bundled with beamer and is documented in beamer's user guide) supports the GIF format.

And, for Linux users, it works on Ubuntu's default PDF viewer (20.04)!

I can't get it to loop though. The problem seems not limited to the GIF format, I tried to work around it using mp4 but it didn't work, see see [loop video clip in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38199/loop-video-clip-in-beamer)

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
[...]
\usepackage{multimedia}
[...]
\movie[<options>]{\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{poster-image}}{my-beautiful-gif.gif}
```